# Proper manage of private nuget packages dependencies between solutions

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

We have 2 solutions.

`SolutionA` is an internal solution where we put reusable code through our products
For the sake of the question, it has only two projects `NugetProjectA` and `NugetProjectB` which has a `project reference` to `NugetProjectA`.

`SolutionB` its a solution that has `package references` towards `SolutionA` via nuget.

The thing that troubles is:

- add new method added in `NugetProjectA`
- add new method in `NugetProjectB` project that uses previous method
- publish new version of `NugetProjectB`
- update nuget reference on `Project` of `SolutionA`
- execute in `Project` newly added method of `NugetProjectB`

Since we didn't publish the `NugetProjectA` updated version, last step described will fail.

This seems to be a easy problem to solution. But imagine this with many more projects in `SolutionB` and many more in `SolutionA`.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you publish `NuGetProjectA` after making changes to it, particularly after modifying `NuGetProjectB` to depend on those changes and publishing `NuGetProjectB`?  Wouldn't publishing that package solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, that is what we do right now. But, as I said, this is a reduced panorama of the real scenario. Imagine `SolutionA` with like 14 projects and many dependencies.

Comment: Not sure this is exactly what you're dealing with, but found this, might be somewhat relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72723880/1399272

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is vague and open-ended, so there isn't a simple, concise answer. Honestly it could easily be a multi-post blog series or even a short book. I'll try to give some general suggestions, but I'm not going to go into a lot of details to avoid making this answer too long.

## Mono-repo vs multiple repos

Just like the microservice craze from a few years ago, you should first ask yourself if you need it. Having all your source code in a single repository and solution might make it feel "legacy", and it sure seems nicer to have a 3 minute build of a component rather than a 30 minute build of a whole system when checking in a 1-line bug fix. But are the problems you listed in your question worth the benefit of a shorter CI build?

On the other extreme, Google may famously run almost everything out of a single repository, but they have teams of people doing nothing more than managing their mono-repo and build system because a large number of developers working on a single repo have a different set of problems. These are engineers not working on customer applications. If their work make other teams more productive, then it can be worthwhile.

You need to figure out what's best for you, but given the problem you described in the question, maybe you have too many repos/solutions and your processes could be faster with fewer mistakes if you consolidate a little.

## Automation

The next best thing is to just use good engineering practises. Automate as much as possible to reduce the risk of human mistakes, including automating processes that validate that manual processes are followed correctly.

- Have the a CI or CD pipeline push packages, so you can't forgot to push dependencies, like in your example.
- There are tools that will automatically generate a version number from the git history based on the number of commits since the versioning config file was checked in. This prevents you from forgetting to increment the package version when you check in a change to the package.
- Have tests to make sure the package works before pushing it. You could make it as simple as making sure that dependencies exist, but you could also go further and have test programs run that use the package to ensure that backwards compatibility isn't broken and that new features actually work as expected. Have these tests run before pushing the package, so if the tests fail, you don't push a bad package.
- You can have a pipeline that will automatically create pull requests on solutions that use a package when a new version of one of your packages is published. You can even automatically merge it, but you'll want to make sure you have real good tests to avoid a buggy package cascading into a huge mess, particularly if you do automatic deployments on successful builds.
- Be creative and think about other ways you can automate your processes to make things easier for yourself and your team.

But be pragmatic about what you automate. There's no point spending a week full time to automate something that only takes you 5 minutes once a month to do manually. But if the manual process sometimes goes wrong and causes hours or days of effort to fix, then that makes automating the process more worthwhile.

## Use modern features

The .NET ecosystem has changed a lot in the last 2-3 years since .NET Core was announced. Now packing with MSBuild (either `dotnet pack` or `msbuild -t:pack`) is easier to create packages than creating `.nuspec` files and making sure you do the right things to get project dependencies packed as nuget dependencies, getting all files in the right places, etc. If your class library uses SDK style projects, then there's nothing extra to do. If your project is a traditional project, you'll need to use `PackageReference` for your NuGet dependencies (or specify `<ProjectStyle>PackageReference</ProjectStyle>` as an MSBuild property in your project file), and then reference the `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` package.

## Version the application, not each package

Like the mono-repo vs multiple repos point, considering versioning all packages in the application with a single version number, rather than versioning each package individually. Yes, this means you'll sometimes (or maybe often) publish a new version of a package that doesn't have any code changes to the previous version, but it simplifies the release considerably. Coupled with packing with MSBuild in the section above, you can create a `Directory.Build.props` file in your repository root, and set the `<Version>` property to your app version, and all projects in the repo will have the same version. So, when you're ready to release, bump the version in a single file and every project and every NuGet packages will have the same version.

## Summary

In an ideal world each component would be reusable in different applications, in a separate source code repository, each package individually versioned using semantic versioning. But in the real world this adds a lot of development time complexity. Your customers may be happier to get bug fixes and new features more quickly, even if the version number of packages are less meaningful. So, make data driven decisions. If you're frequently having dependency version problems, reduce your dependencies so there are fewer things that can go wrong.

Don't get me wrong, there are many good reasons to have multiple projects, multiple solutions, multiple repositories. Just make sure that the reason you're doing them is because it helps your team/company be more productive, not for idealistic reasons that are slowing you down or causing bugs.